# PHP "Call to undefined method" error when trying to get the result of a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've had this error for a while and I can't find a solution to it. This is the php file:

```
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "database"); // The actual php file has the real credentials.
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

var_dump($mysqli);
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
var_dump($stmt);
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE a=?;')) {

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['data']);

    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt);
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "<table border=1>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['a'] . "</td><td>" . $row['b'] . "</td><td>" . $row['c'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

I intended this to find all the rows in the table "test" where a=[whatever the user said] without the risk of a sql injection. Instead, it produces this on the webpage:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (0) { } object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (0) { } object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (0) { }
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /public_html/test/test.php on line 20
```

I realize that the `object(mysqli)#1 (0)...` is from the var_dumps I have. I put those in to see if it was being set to null at any point in the program.

I even copied and pasted the example on this PHP manual page but I still got this error.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Edit: I updated to version 5.3.27 but the error is still there.

Comment: Is your PHP version `>= 5.3` as stated in the doc page you linked ?

Comment: @Jerska Turns out my PHP version is 5.2.17. Not sure how to update it. I'm starting a live chat with my web host right now about it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to match your real problem.

Comment: @Jerska I updated to 5.3.27 but I'm still getting those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two immediate possibilities:

- Quote from the man page, first comment:

> Please note that this method requires the mysqlnd driver.
>   Othervise you will get this error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
>
> `PHP` version isn't `>= 5.3`

Comment: I couldn't find that driver with phpinfo(), but I have very limited control about how the server is handled. I think I'm gonna just bite the bullet and learn PDO. I hear it's better anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry I can't help you more than this.